# Grafana Запрос процентное отношение

Tags: alert, grafana

В графана есть дашборд, который строится по запросу:

rate(http_request_duration_seconds_sum{handler="/createmag",method="POST",status="200"}[$__rate_interval])
/rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count{handler="/createmag",method="POST",status="200"}[$__rate_interval])

Нужно сделать Алерт. Сейчас первая часть запроса время создания в секундах, вторая часть - количество самих запросов.

Алерт должен быть вида, если количество create длительностью более 3 секунд превышает 5% от общего числа create за 15 минут - то Алерт.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копнуть, куда посмотреть?